# OpenSSL vs NSS from FIPS-140-2 and Suite B perspective?

Tags: openssl, fips

Does anyone know of any work/papers/articles comparing the relative strengths and weaknesses of NSS and OpenSSL?

> EDIT: In case there aren't any existing documents/articles, I would
>   certainly appreciate some information from your own experiences on
>   either libraries.

The primary context is FIP-140-2 certification (since both libraries claim certification) and wider compatibility with Suite B ciphers.

The secondary context for comparison would be ease of development on Linux and Windows via C/C++ and C# (mostly C# barring heavy duty stuff in C/C++)

Bonus points if it also considers developer/community momentum, validation/certification frequency, execution speed, etc.

> Post bounty status update: Over 130 views and a bounty that expired - guessing not too many people in the world really know about Crypto libraries (esp in light of how OpenSSL's Heartbleed issue went unnoticed for over 2 years despite open source)

Comment: Google needed to decide wether to use OpenSSL or NSS once and made a [comparison](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ML11ZyyMpnAr6clIAwWrXD53pQgNR-DppMYwt9XvE6s/edit?pli=1#heading=h.796vnynwkfzg "Chrome: From NSS to OpenSSL"). FIPS 140-2 is a "U.S. government computer security standard" from 2002 - the value of such a thing is at your own discretion. [Both](https://www.openssl.org/docs/fips/fipsnotes.html "OpenSSL and FIPS 140-2") imlementations have received [validations](https://wiki.mozilla.org/FIPS_Validation "FIPS Validation")